# jQuery return false; Breaks Checkbox

Tags: jquery, html

Ok, so I have a dropdown login box, which uses this code for dropdown:

```
$('#header #login > a').click(function(){
    if($('#header #login').hasClass('open')){
        $('#header #login').removeClass('open');
    }
    else{
        $('#header #login').addClass('open');
    }
    return false;
});
$('#header #login').click(function(){
    return false;
});
$(document).click(function(){
    $('#header #login').removeClass('open');
});
```

The only problem is that the return false is breaking the checkbox that I've added to the login box...
Anybody know how to fix this?

EDIT: Ok, so the correct way to do this is:

```
$('#header #login > a').click(function(e){
    if($('#header #login').hasClass('open')){
        $('#header #login').removeClass('open');
    }
    else{
        $('#header #login').addClass('open');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('#header #login').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function(){
    $('#header #login').removeClass('open');
});
```

Comment: in what way is the checkbox Broken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read this: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just don't know how to fix that and still have my dropdown login box work.

Answer (score 1):

This code here

```
$('#header #login').click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Will prevent the checkbox being ticked. As the checkbox is in side the login div?

You need to remove it. What is the point of it?